# ExpressionEngine If no categories results, show nothing

Tags: html, expressionengine, categories, conditional-statements

I am using ExpressionEngine 2.2.1 And am trying to show a section of my page based on categories. If no entries have a certain category selected, I would like to hide the entire section. For example, I have a website the lists information about an event that will eventually have competitors in it. I would like the page to exist before the competitors are selected, then would like to add competitors to the appropriate category once they have been selected. That section would have a header that says "competitors." If there are no competitors assigned to that category yet, I not only don't want it to show space for the competitors, but I would like to also hide the header. How can I create conditionals based on categories? Here the applicable portion of my current code based on my research (http://expressionengine.com/archived_forums/viewthread/136676/#759900) that is not working:

```
{if “{categories show_group=“4”}{category_name}{/categories}” != “”}
   {categories}     
      <h2>COMPETITORS</h2>
      {exp:channel:entries  channel="competitor_profiles_en" category_url_title="london_2d_en" orderby="date"  limit="8"  }
         <div class="xx">{competitor_image}</div>
      {/exp:channel:entries}
   {/categories}
{if:else}
show nothing
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do this?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="competitor_profiles_en" category_url_title="london_2d_en" orderby="date" limit="8"} 
    {if count == "1"}<h2>COMPETITORS</h2>{/if}
    <div class="xx">{competitor_image}</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Or, if you're doing this while looping through all categories:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="competitor_profiles_en" show_empty="no"}

    <h1>{category_name}</h1>
    {category_description}

    <h2>COMPETITORS</h2>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="competitor_profiles_en" category="{category_id}" orderby="date" limit="8"}
        <div class="xx">{competitor_image}</div>
    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Note that if you have many categories, this nesting of tags can lead to a sizeable performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by adding `parse="inward"` to the `channel:entries` tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" parse="inward"}
```

And then the following if statement:

```
{if '{categories show="135"}{category_name}{/categories}' != ""}
```

Obviously replace your channel and category IDs above. So the complete code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" parse="inward"}
    {if '{categories show="135"}{category_name}{/categories}' != ""}
        {!-- do something here --}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the complete code?

The {categories}{/categories} looping pair is only available within a channel:entries tag pair.

I'm not completely following what you are trying to do, but there is a conditional that you can use within the channel:entries loop if there are no results based on the use of the tag:

[{if_no_results}](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#if-no-results).

Possibly this could be used to create the view you want when the template is loaded in category mode, but there are no entries assigned to the category.